# Number of Elements in a page

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

While I was playing with Prototypejs javascript library, I found that

`$$("*").length` < `document.getElementsByTagName("*").length`

I wonder why prototypejs always gives lower number.

---

### EDIT

After Dr.Molle's Answer, I tried in another page where I found the length difference is 3 not always 1.  Then I found that

a.  which begins with "!" after the the angle bracket    (reported as 1 in total)

b. <!--  --> comment tag (there were 2 comment tag in the page)               (reported as 2 in total)

I wonder "!" also shows as tagName along with other tag e.g. div, span,script, etc.

The following code has been used in IE's Developer Tool

```
var allEles=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
$A(allEles).each(function(el){
console.log(el.tagName);
});
```

shows ..

```
LOG: !

LOG: HTML

LOG: HEAD
```

Comment: Strange. Maybe take a peek into the contents?

Comment: It doesn't always happen (run `document.getElementsByTagName("*").length == $$("*").length` on http://www.prototypejs.org/). You should show us the page this occured on.

Comment: Try this from here  http://nazmulweb.com/site5/demo/,
$$("*").length returns 61, whereas
document.getElementsByTagName('*').length returns 62

Comment: Try another, http://nazmulweb.com/site5/demo/tricks/Default.aspx, returns different length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like in MSIE(I only see it happen there) getElementsByTagName() fetches the `<!DOCTYPE>` too, but $$() don't.

If a DOCTYPE is given IE reports for the first element in `getElementsByTagName('*')` a tagName **!** and nodeType **8**

Regarding to that nodeType it seems like the DOCTYPE is considered as a comment-node(what nodeType 8 stands for), so the primary fault there is that MSIE fetches comments when using `getElementsByTagName()`